# Rectangle keeps going off panel(Screen)

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

Can anybody tell me how I can stop the rectangles from going off the panel (screen) in my game? The rectangles move side by side with keystrokes.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: what do you want to happen when the bat reaches the edge of the panel? just stop?

Comment: hi i am new to stack overflow and im also new to java

Comment: hi @Sionnach733 yes i just want to make the bat stop, because at the moment it goes off screen when you carry on pressing the keys

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should do :
1. Keep a track of `(x,y)` coordinates of your rectangles.
2. Ensure that  `x + width` of your rectangle is not greater than width of the `JPanel` *for checking the collision with right edge*
3.  Ensure that `x` is not less than 0 *to check the collision left edge*.
4. Ensure that `y + height` is not greater than height of the `JPanel`*to check the collision with bottom edge*

Can you guess what it will be for the top edge ?

Comment: hi will this be done by an if statement like i said im a novice. sorry for dumb questions

Comment: Yep. `if` statements ;-) Do you have a good book that will teach you step-by-step ?

Comment: no i dont have a book.  and will this if statement be done in the drawing panel class?

Comment: @user2112303 You are trying to swallow a big chunk. [Have a look at this book](http://www.amazon.com/Ivor-Hortons-Beginning-Java-Horton/dp/0470404140/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1390415221&sr=8-1&keywords=Beginning+Java+7+Ivor+Horton)

Comment: @user2112303 your if statements should go in your action methods. You need to check the x locations. If they are not within the bounds of the screen, do nothing, else, move

Comment: hi sorry to be and idiot but is there a method for bounds or something? and is the pseudo code going to be something like if(x !withinBounds){;}else{move bat}

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

See [Motion With the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for working examples. The examples will also do boundary checking to make sure the component is contained within its parents bounds.

Comment: hi i have used key bindings for the bat

Comment: @user2112303 Try not to mix APIs, use KeyBindings for all you key board interactions